# static distance between the panels

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dynamically created N panels, the distance between them in height 15px

```
panel.Location = new Point (x, y);  
y = panel.Bottom + 15;
```

I can make the width of the smaller, and so I need distance in height between the panels was always 15px
I have a method with different checks for resize, and I try changes distance, but it always works differently...

```
public void checkResize(string msg_out, object panel_sender, object text_msg_sender, int panHei, int numbs)
{
    Panel pan_item = (Panel)panel_sender;
    Label lab_item = (Label)text_msg_sender;
    char[] msg_arr = msg_out.ToCharArray();
    int panWidRaz = 308 - pan_item.Width;
    int panWidw = pan_item.Width;
    if (int.Parse(pan_item.Name) != numbs - 1)
    {
        if (panWidw < buff)
        {
            /* if (panWidRaz % 15 == 0)
            {
                for (int i = int.Parse(pan_item.Name); i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    panel1.Controls[i.ToString()].Location = new Point(panel1.Controls[i.ToString()].Location.X, panel1.Controls[i.ToString()].Location.Y + 1);
                }
            }*/
        //width control becomes smaller panels are becoming more in height, it is necessary that the distance between the panels remained 15px
        }
        if (panWidw > buff)
        {
            /*if (panWidRaz % 15 == 0)
            {
                for (int i = int.Parse(pan_item.Name); i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    panel1.Controls[i.ToString()].Location = new Point(panel1.Controls[i.ToString()].Location.X, panel1.Controls[i.ToString()].Location.Y - 1);
                }
            }*/
        //width control becomes bigger panels are becoming less in height, it is necessary that the distance between the panels remained 15px
        }
        buffCountPan++;
        if (buffCountPan == panel1.Controls.Count - 1)
        {
            buff = panWidw;
            buffCountPan = 0;
        }

        if (msg_arr.Length > 26)
        {
            int panWid = (308 - pan_item.Width) / 5;
            int panWidLab = 308 - pan_item.Width;
            pan_item.Height = panHei + panWid;
            lab_item.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300 - panWidLab, 100);
            lab_item.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(300 - panWidLab, 14);
        }
    } 
}
```

I can't post image here... reputation... i make scrin of work my panel
http://pixs.ru/showimage/Bezimeni1p_9639414_8969341.png

Comment: "Always works differently", in what way? Also, your code contains two `if` blocks which are completely commented out. Does the problem happen with them enabled or?

Comment: `var distanceHorizontal = panelRight.Left - (panelLeft.Left + panelLeft.Width); var distanceVertical = panelUnder.Top - (panelAbove.Top + panelAbove.Height);`?

Comment: i'm posted scrin of panel... you can see the problem..

Comment: Oh, you have a parent control and inside it a couple of panels and when the parent control changes in size, you want to adjust the size (height) of the panels inside. Okay, so you probably have a `marginTop`, `marginBottom`, `panelCount` and `distance = 15`. The new height for each panel would be `newHeight = (totalHeight - marginTop - marginBottom - (panelCount * distance)) / panelCount`. Then you loop through the `controls.OfType<Panel>().OrderBy(x => x.Top).ToList()`, run a `count` and set each `panel.Height = newHeight` and `panel.Top = marginTop + (count * (newHeight + distance))`.

Comment: Look at the SplitContainer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) and Splitter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitter.aspx) controls.

Comment: Okay, you get the new height of the panel another way. Then sum the height of each panel so far in the loop and set `panel.Top = marginTop + (count * distance) + sumOfHeights`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it simple, when you add those panel which i guess is done dynamically. You can set the panel.tag = "[Order]". so an order number assign so you know which one is first on top and the second and go on...

```
Const int MinimumStartLocation = 0;
Const int DistanceBetweenPanel = 15;

private void setPanelLocation(Panel pnl)
{
    // retreive the order of this panel
    int iPanelOrder = Convert.ToInt32(pnl.Tag);

    // the first panel must show on top and have specific location
    if(iPanelOrder == 0)
    {
         pnl.Top = MinimumStartLocation;
    }
    else
    {
         // set the top of the panel to the bottom value of the panel just before him in the order plus the constant
         pnl.Top = this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().ToList().Find(pan => Convert.ToInt32(pan.Tag) == iPanelOrder -1).Bottom + DistanceBetweenPanel;
    }
}
```

now use this LINQ command it will call the method above for each panel in the proper order.

```
this.Controls.OfType<Panel>().OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Tag)).ToList().ForEach(pan => setPanelLocation(pan));
```

here a sample project quickly done [download here](http://www.sendspace.com/file/drdgir)

Edit: updated link

Comment: sorry. i dotn have VS here couldnt test. missing .ToList()

this.controls.OfType<Panel>().ToList().Find()

Comment: you need to start the index at 0 for the first panel. It will not work if you first panel.tag = "1"

Comment: just added sample project download link to my answer. i could open a VM with VS :) it lag but it works

Comment: will be realy thankful if you look my code... cuz your link doesn't work "Server Error in '/' Application." http://dfiles.ru/files/npzqvl1j2?redirect

Comment: i've updated the link the other one doesnt work for me either. their server have issues i think. anyway i looked at your project and you are using a usercontrol. i can't debug properly. not sure which contro lis which bu i have the feeling the issue is because of the control not being a container. first look at my new updated link so you understand what the code is doing and second for your code i suggest you create a `private List<Panel> lstPanels = new List<Panel>();` in your userconrol so you add all your panels in there and as well inside the usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth taking a look at the [Flow Layout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx). When you add a control to a flow layout panel it will automatically be positioned either to the left, right, top or bottom of any existing controls within that flow layout panel (depending on the layout direction property that you specify).

Similarly, if you remove or resize a control contained within a flow layout panel the positions of the controls will be automatically updated for you.

In your case it should be as simple as adding a new flow layout panel to your form then, for each panel that you add to the flow layout panel, setting the top margin to 15px and the bottom margin to 0px; the flow layout panel will take care of the rest. When panels are added, removed or resized the flow layout panel will ensure that they are still displayed correctly with a margin of 15px between them.